# Ubuntu updates crash NVIDIA drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, nvidia-geforce

I have been using Ubuntu for a few years, on a few separate machines, and I seem to be running into a recurrent issue with updates, on all machines, both in 22.04 and previously in 20.04. Once in a while, some security update crashes my NVIDIA drivers. On most of my fresh installs, I have installed NVIDIA, CUDA and cuDNN manually according to NVIDIA’s instructions, although on a few occasions I have instead installed GPU things directly during the Ubuntu installation checking the box with 3rd party software.

Either way, I have a fully functional machine, when some Ubuntu update crashes NVIDIA. The first times this happened I tried to reinstall NVIDIA drivers and CUDA, but failed, wasting quite some time. So when this happens, I roll back my system to an earlier snapshop and refrain from installing upcoming security updates, and after some time, I reinstall Ubuntu from scratch.

When this happens, there are no pending updates to anything NVIDIA, GPU, CUDA etc. I believe that the culprit are some (not all) new Linux kernels.

Currently, I am running:

```
Ubuntu 22.04.1 
Linux kernel: 6.2.0-39-generic 
GPU: GeForce RTX 3080 Ti
NVIDIA Driver Version: 530.30.02     
CUDA Version: 12.1
```

I have a pending update to kernel version 6.5.0, which crashes my NVIDIA drivers (I have rolled back to an earlier snapshot since that happened).

Needless to say, this is rather annoying. So I wonder:

1. Am I the only one who gets their NVIDIA drivers crashed by Ubuntu updates, or is this a common problem?
2. What is the actual cause of this?
3. Is there a smoother way to fix the problem than making a new fresh install?

Comment: It's not the new kernels, it's the fact that they cannot rebuild the Nvidia module.  The "Nvidia drivers" from the Canonical repositories have all the rebuild code to do this when a kernel (or Nvidia driver) updates, third party drivers typically do not (or do not do this successfully).

Comment: Thank you @ubfan1 for your reply. How can this issue be avoided then?

Comment: There are lots of answers here for installing CUDA (1077061,1219761,...).  First just try the cuda and cudnn packages the standard repos offer. If any other software (tensorflow,...) require specific version, use the Nvidia .run script, reject any offer of Nvidia drivers, and option the lib/bin locations to be under the /usr/local/cuda-xxx/lib (bin) dirs. Remember, CUDA is just an app, don't let it mess with drivers or system libraries -- a sure way to confuse the update process.